# Backup all my files on external hard disk on Ubuntu using the tty-terminal

Tags: backup

Is there a way to backup files from the tty terminal? I'm not able to start Ubuntu and none of the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

work. I was getting the error of having unmet dependencies and in trying to fix that I ended up uninstalling a lot of packages.

So I'm uninstalling Ubuntu 14.10 and installing 15.04 afresh. Before that I need to backup my files but I only have access to tty terminal.
Note that I have windows 8 + Ubuntu 14.10 dual boot...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to copy all of your standard Ubuntu data files from the disk is to login to TTY1 and:

1. Do a `ls /dev/?d?`
2. Insert an external disk, and do another `ls /dev/?d?`
3. Subtract **the output** from step 1 from the output from step 2 and you should be left with the device name of the external HDD.  This should take the form of `XdYN` where `X` is `s` or `h` depending on your hardware, `Y` is a letter and `N` is a number (probably `1`)
4. Type:

   ```
   mkdir /media/$USER/external
   ```

   Ensure you substitute `XdYN` for the correct letters from step 3 in the following command:

   ```
   mount /dev/XdYN /media/$USER/external
   ```
5. Copy-paste the following *leaving out any data you don't want*:

   ```
   cd /media/$USER/external
   mkdir bin
   mkdir Desktop
   mkdir Documents
   mkdir Downloads
   mkdir Music
   mkdir Pictures                 
   mkdir Public
   mkdir Templates
   mkdir Videos

   cd /
   cp --recursive --preserve=time /home/$USER/bin /media/$USER/external/bin
   cp --recursive --preserve=time /home/$USER/Desktop /media/$USER/external/Desktop
   cp --recursive --preserve=time /home/$USER/Documents /media/$USER/external/Documents
   cp --recursive --preserve=time /home/$USER/Downloads /media/$USER/external/Downloads
   cp --recursive --preserve=time /home/$USER/Music /media/$USER/external/Music
   cp --recursive --preserve=time /home/$USER/Pictures /media/$USER/external/Pictures
   cp --recursive --preserve=time /home/$USER/Public /media/$USER/external/Public
   cp --recursive --preserve=time /home/$USER/Templates /media/$USER/external/Templates
   cp --recursive --preserve=time /home/$USER/Videos /media/$USER/external/Videos
   ```

E.g. If you don't want to copy your video files, do not copy-paste the lines including `Videos` above.

### That's it!

You've got a back-up of all your important files on an external disk!